# A question regarding signal analysis

Tags: signal-processing

I'm quite new to the topic but I know about LTI systems, convolution and Laplace transforms as a concept. I also know the meaning of transient and steady state analysis.

I was reading an article on the subject but stuck at some point.

What is meant by the following statement:

> "Step signal, a ramp signal, and periodic signal are for time domain
>   analysis. Only an impulse signal is essential for steady-state
>   analysis."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impulse response entirely characterizes an LTI system.  If you have the impulse response, and the system is LTI, you have all the information there is to have.  Hence, "only".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what it means is that:

As the U(s) of an impulse is 1 (in the case of unary impulse), when falculating the output Y(s) = F(s)*U(s) then Y(s) = F(s), and as you have the TF it is only theory to get the Ess (error in steady state) by the number of poles in the origin.

[Explanation of types and Ess](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_Ess)